# How to add Swagger UI documentation for gRPC calls in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, grpc, grpc-java

Let's imagine I have a multimodule project, which has two micro services named serviceA and serviceB.

serviceA makes RPC calls to serviceB.

Is there any way that I can document these RPC calls to Swagger UI?

Comment: This should probably help 

https://swagger.io/resources/articles/documenting-apis-with-swagger/#how-to-generate-openapi-from-existing-apis-7 ?